# saving jpeg to file on server, "../uploads/" doesn't work but "\uploads\\" does

Tags: php

So, here is my basic file structure:

```
- public_html/
--index.php
---php/
---imageUpload.php
--uploads/
```

I have got a PHP script which works fine, up until it comes to execute `imagejpeg()` command, this is what mine looks like:

```
imagejpeg($images_fin,"../uploads/".$new_images); //Save image to file
```

Obviously I have got `../` as I want to go back a folder, as `uploads/` is in the root directory. If I try that though I get this error:

> PHP Error Message Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open
>   '../uploads/' for writing: Is a directory in
>   /home/a9990485/public_html/php/uploadImage.php on line 42

However, if I change my imagejpeg to this:

```
imagejpeg($images_fin,"..\uploads\\".$new_images); //Save image to file
```

It just creates a new folder called `..\uploads\\` in my `php/` folder and the image saves in there. What is going on, why can't I go back into my root directory and save it in my uploads folder!

I have tried `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/public_html/uploads/"` but I get an error saying I have no access to the folder than as i'm assuming it's trying to go too far back into the hosts file structure.

Comment: probable reason $new_images is empty. echo { "../uploads/".$new_images } and please post the path here

Comment: I said in my post though, that the new images DOES get created within the folder it makes.. so it can't be empty as it creates the image.

Comment: Ooooh, strange, so yeah it does seem to be empty, so it's creating an image with the file name `../uploads/` as I can click and open the image lol!

Comment: I'm an idiot, simple mistake. I didn't change the `$new_images` variable to the variable that has got the new filename! @georoot, make that your answer please.

Comment: please mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probable reason for this is $new_images variable is empty. The php error says

```
Unable to open '../uploads/' for writing
```

which means it is trying to open ../uploads/ which is a folder and not a file